# React Hooks - "Function components cannot be given refs" with useRef

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-hooks, styled-components

I'm using styled-components, FontAwesome and React Hooks to create an icon & label unit (`Box.js`) for a header/navbar. Inside the Box there is a `Container` which holds both the `Icon` and `Label`. I want both the `Icon` and `Label` to change colors together when you hover over **either** of them which is why I put `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` on the `Container` component. I was loosely following [this guide](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/59/Create-a-componentDidMount-useEffect-hook-in-React) to implement something like that.

Before following the link, I tried this [useHover](https://usehooks.com/useHover/) hook which did not give me an error message but produced no effect (not even console.log output when I hovered over).

I've googled the error message, but it looks like existing StackOverflow posts and React issues on Github are **not** dealing with Hooks. The error messages reported in those are also slightly different: `Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.` My error message does not have the word "stateless."

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/q7rwe

Expected: all the child elements of `Container` (i.e. `Icon` and `Label`) change to the color green when the mouse hovers over any one child element.

Actual: I get the following error message -

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `Box`.
    in Icon (created by Box)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div (created by Box)
    in Box (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
```

Comment: This is what it looks like with forwardRef, just in case https://codesandbox.io/embed/useref-error-7tere. The issue is FontAwesomeIcon does does not support ref. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/pull/220) that should resolve this issue as soon as it's merged.

Comment: Thanks for the links @AlexanderStaroselsky! Wasn't aware of the FontAwesome issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few flaws in your current approach.

First of all, you should not give a `ref` to a functional component.

But, even if you do, you won't be able to use the `ref` to change color given your current structure, because `useEffect` will be activated after rendering and immediately make the component's color green because `ref.current` will exist.

You have `isHovered` state already. Just use this for changing color.

I have updated your code to better implement the behavior you want. Try it!

#### Box.js

```
const Box = () => {
  const [isHovered, setHovered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Container
      onMouseOver={() => setHovered(true)}
      onMouseOut={() => setHovered(false)}
    >
      <Icon isHovered={isHovered} />
      <Label isHovered={isHovered} />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

#### Icon.js

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCoffee } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
const Icon = props => {
  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      icon={faCoffee}
      color={props.isHovered ? "green" : "black"}
    />
  );
};

export default Icon;
```

#### Label.js

```
import React from "react";
const Label = props => {
  return (
    <p style={{ color: props.isHovered ? "green" : "black" }}>
      Label goes here
    </p>
  );
};
export default Label;
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/useref-error-xjf48

Comment: thank you @bkm412 @Ryan ! I'm wondering if you could clarify why you cannot give a `ref` to a functional component? I thought that was the point of `useRef` being included in the new Hooks API.

Comment: useRef is used for access HTML element. Like controll input or get scrollheight of div and so on. useRef is not for get functional component. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html